# Unable to import tensorflow and make_interpreter from pycoral

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4, google-coral

When importing **tensorflow** and **make_interpreter** from **pycoral** in the same python file it gives the following error:

```
import tensorflow
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter
```

-->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joran/tflite/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/conflict.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycoral/utils/edgetpu.py", line 32, in <module>
    import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tflite_runtime import _pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper as _interpreter_wrapper
ImportError: generic_type: type "InterpreterWrapper" is already registered!
```

I am running it on the Raspberry Pi 4 using miniforge (conda) as virtual environment.
The same program works fine on Ubuntu 20.04. I have made sure all the installed packages are the same version as the Ubuntu version. If I change the order of the import the following error rises:

```
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter 
import tensorflow
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joran/tflite/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/conflict.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._api.v2 import compat
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/compat/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/compat/v1/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import lite
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/lite/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import experimental
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/lite/experimental/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import authoring
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/lite/experimental/authoring/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python.authoring.authoring import compatible
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/authoring/authoring.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python import lite
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/joran/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter_wrapper import _pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper as _interpreter_wrapper
ImportError: generic_type: type "InterpreterWrapper" is already registered!
```

Both import **_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper as _interpreter_wrapper**, should the scope not be limited?

I have tried several other python and tensorflow versions and environments. Always the same error. Any way of fixing this? So both can be imported without errors. Commenting out the import did not work.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: no, I'm sorry. I was not able to get it to work without conflicts